# Confusion with PHP Namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm using php for my new project which is quite large. I feel the need to employ namespaces.

I have read many docs on it, but am confused practically about. Here is the scenario:

I have defined the following namespace and class:

```
namespace urlNS;

class URL 
{
// content of the class
}
```

And then in another file, I want to define a class in the same namespace (urlNS) and also extend the URL class (which is a subset of urlNS namespace), and to do this, I have done:

```
namespace urlNS:

class Inc extends urlNS\url
{
// content 
}
```

Now, I wanted to make use of a defined namespace twice (or even more), did I do it in a right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base class definition:

```
<?php
namespace urlNS;

class URL {}
```

Subclass:

```
<?php
namespace urlNS;

class Inc extends URL {}
```

Using:

```
<?php
$url = new urlNS\URL();
$suburl = new urlNS\Inc();
```

Or with `use` keyword:

```
<?php
use urlNS\URL;

$url = URL();
```